TypeScript Error with useReducer and Generic Types: Unable to Infer Type 'T'
Playground Link
why is the type of my initial data "unkown" when I've specified that its a generic?
import { useEffect, useReducer } from "react";

type Action<T> =
  | { type: "FETCH_INIT" }
  | { type: "FETCH_FAIL" }
  | { type: "FETCH_SUCCESS"; data: T };
  
interface FetchState<T> {
  isLoading: boolean;
  isError: boolean;
  data: T;
}
  
function fetchDataReducer<T>(
  state: FetchState<T>,
  action: Action<T>
): FetchState<T> {
 switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCH_INIT":
      return { ...state, isLoading: true, isError: false };

    case "FETCH_FAIL":
      return { ...state, isLoading: false, isError: true };

    case "FETCH_SUCCESS":
      return { ...state, isLoading: false, isError: false, data: action.data };

    default:
      return { ...state };
  }
}
  
export default function useFetchOnMount<T>(
  url: string,
  initialData: T
): FetchState<T> {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(fetchDataReducer, {
    isLoading: true,
    isError: false,
    data: initialData,
  });
  
  useEffect(() => {
    let didCancel = false;
  
    async function fetchData() {
      dispatch({ type: "FETCH_INIT" });
      try {
        const response = await fetch(url, {
          method: "GET",
        });
  
        if (!response.ok) {
          dispatch({ type: "FETCH_FAIL" });
        }
  
        const data = await response.json();
        if (!didCancel && response.ok) {
          dispatch({ type: "FETCH_SUCCESS", data: data });
        }
      } catch (error) {
        if (!didCancel) {
          dispatch({ type: "FETCH_FAIL" });
        }
      }
    }

    fetchData();

    return () => {
      didCancel = true;
    };
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
  return state;
}

The initialData is "unknown" I want it so that it its not "unknown" and takes the type of the generic.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. • Please [edit] to format your code properly as a single code block. • The word is "unknown", not "unkown"; consider editing to help future searches. • TypeScript cannot instantiate generic type arguments when passing generic functions around; it only can do so when calling the function, but since you're not calling fetchDataReducer directly you get unknown. If you want T you can use an instantiation expression as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write a full answer; if not, what's missing?

Pass the generic type T through to your fetchDataReducer reducer function so it can correctly type the state it operates over, e.g. const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(fetchDataReducer<T>, .....);. Voting to close as "not reproducible or was caused by typo". Cheers.
